# How to find out if a class member is static and a field in Java

Tags: java, reflection

How do you find out whether a member of a class is static and a field? 
I tried using the .getModifiers() method but it didn't return the desired result.

- bcMember:

  - member identifier
  - identifer of class that contains this member
  - boolean: true if member is static, false otherwise
  - boolean: true if member is a field; false otherwise
  - qualified name of member's (return) type
  - array qualifier: ' ' means return type is not an array, '[ ]' is a 1D array, '[ ][ ]' is a 2D array, and so on.
  - signature of member: for a field, it is the name of the field. For a method, it is the name of the method followed by a list of its parameters.

The desired output for the yparser.connection package is:

```
bcClass(c0,'yparser.connection','Object').

/* public Constructors */
bcMember(m0,c0,true,false,'yparser.connection','','connection(String,String,String,String,String,String)').

/* public Fields */
bcMember(m1,c0,true,true,'String','','quote').
bcMember(m2,c0,true,true,'String','','comma').
bcMember(m3,c0,false,true,'String','','name1').
bcMember(m4,c0,false,true,'String','','role1').
bcMember(m5,c0,false,true,'String','','end1').
bcMember(m6,c0,false,true,'String','','name2').
bcMember(m7,c0,false,true,'String','','role2').
bcMember(m8,c0,false,true,'String','','end2').

/* public Methods */
bcMember(m9,c0,true,false,'void','','dump()').
```

Comment: You either have a Method, a Field, or a Class. There's no common Member supertype.

Comment: So what result did it return? And what were you expecting?

Comment: Sorry, by member I meant fields and methods (constructors are methods too right?

Comment: I typed this: Modifier.isStatic(cons.getModifiers()) where cons is the declared constructors of a class returned from .getDeclaredConstructors() and it returned false, when the correct output is supposed to be one for my particular case that I'm testing against.

Comment: Since when is a constructor static?

Comment: So you already know it's a constructor, so it isn't a field. And you also tested whether the constructor is static, which it isn't, and you got some unstated and allegedly incorrect (or at least 'undesired') result, which I sincerely hope was `false`. So what's the problem?

Comment: Nobody can tell what the third column is in that mess. Edit it into your question, and make sure to format it properly. NB you still haven't asked an intelligible question. 'Didn't return the desired result' and 'stuck' are not problem descriptions. Can you also please note that this isn't a discussion forum, it is a Q&A site. Questions that don't maker sense are very likely to be deleted.

Comment: Stop it. ***Edit the desired output into your question.*** And you've already been told several times that constructors aren't static, so (a) `isStatic()` is working correctly, and (b) that column should be `false`, not `true`. So far the only identifiable problems here stem from your incorrect expectations.

Comment: If constructors can't be static, I guess the "correct" output specified to me is wrong then and that's why I got stuck not knowing why it was returning false.

Comment: I suggest you print the `javap` output from that class, and compare it to these incorrect expectations. Show it to whoever specified them. Post it here, again edited into your question.

Answer (score 3):

You know it's a field because it's a `Field` object.

To determine if it's static:

```
if(Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers()))
    System.out.println("Field is static!");
```

or

```
if((f.getModifiers() & Modifier.STATIC) != 0)
    System.out.println("Field is static!");
```

Comment: And how do you see if it is a Field object?

Comment: @PresidentNick because you wrote `Field f;` at some point. (If you only have an `Object` reference, then you use `instanceof`. Same way you'd tell if an object was a `String`)

Comment: @PresidentNick That  question doesn't make sense. There is no way you can get a class member reflection object without *already knowing* whether it's a field or a method. Because that's what you asked for: one or the other. Strong typing also tells you. And if for some unknown reason you stored the result in an Object you can still use `instanceof` to disambiguate.

Comment: instanceof, that's what I was looking for, thank you. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @PresidentNick So you called `getFields()` or `getDeclaredFields()`, stored the result in an `Object[]`, and then forgot what method you called, so you have to figure it out at runtime? Why?

Comment: I haven't called getFields() yet on the class I'm observing, just getDeclaredConstructors() and my knowledge of this isn't that good, but now that you pointed that getFields() method I will use that. I didn't know constructors couldn't be fields (I'm sorry, I'm new to this, I'm currently learning it)

Comment: So if you got the constructors why are you asking if they're fields? This isn't making any sense. If you don't know the difference between a constructor and a field you're several months premature in using Reflection.

Comment: "I just dialed a phone number, how do I know whether I called my boss or my wife?"

Comment: Well this is trail and error I guess, and I'm learning from it.

Comment: if (phone_number instanceof wife)

Comment: @PresidentNick It doesn't have to be trial and error. You could always look it up.

Comment: @PresidentNick nope, you'd know you if called your wife because you typed in her number, or chose her on your contacts list!

Answer (score 1):

```
fields[] fld= TheClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field fldd : fld) {
    if (java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(fldd.getModifiers())) {
        //Then the fldd is static
    }
}
```